# How to print the transpose of a given string

Tags: java, string

My question goes like this.
   Can any one help me out how to print the transpose of given element.

Can any one help me out how to print the transpose of given element. 
I dont know how to apply for loop for this.please help me on this this
was the question asked by interviewer when i attended interview in MNC company.

I know how to print it in reverse order but am not getting how to do it using transpose.

Help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

```
                     abc
                     def 
                       g
```

i want to print transpose of this element like this

```
                    ad
                    be
                    cfg
```

How can i do this using java

Comment: There's no built-in function for that. Decompose into a 2D array and iterate over that.

Comment: You need to at least tell us how did you read the input.

Comment: show us that what you have tried, we will have a better view of your efforts and we will help you in your code....

Comment: public class Trans {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  
  int[][] a = { { a, b, c }, { d, e, f }, { , , g } };
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    System.out.print(a[i][j]);
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   for (int j = i + 1; j < 3; j++) {
    int temp = a[i][j];
    
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
  
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    System.out.print(a[i][j]);
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 2):

i am not providing you the code. Here is my hint

To make it transpose you need to interchange the row and column. Thing the input string as a 3x3 square matrix where each letter is a element. Now store the input in a 2d array. After storing transpose it just by printing column values with respect to row values.

```
                  c1   c2   c3
             r1   a     b    c
             r2   d     e    f 
             r3              g
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the distance counts only swaps, here is an idea based on permutations, that runs in linear time.

The first step of the algorithm is ensuring that the two strings are really equivalent in their character contents. This can be done in linear time using a hash table (or a fixed array that covers all the alphabet). If they are not, then s2 can't be considered a permutation of s1, and the "swap count" is irrelevant.

The second step counts the minimum number of swaps required to transform s2 to s1. This can be done by inspecting the permutation p that corresponds to the transformation from s1 to s2. For example, if s1="abcde" and s2="badce", then p=(2,1,4,3,5), meaning that position 1 contains element #2, position 2 contains element #1, etc. This permutation can be broke up into permutation cycles in linear time. The cycles in the example are (2,1) (4,3) and (5). The minimum swap count is the total count of the swaps required per cycle. A cycle of length k requires k-1 swaps in order to "fix it". Therefore, The number of swaps is N-C, where N is the string length and C is the number of cycles. In our example, the result is 2 (swap 1,2 and then 3,4).

Now, there are two problems here, and I think I'm too tired to solve them right now :)

1) My solution assumes that no character is repeated, which is not always the case. Some adjustment is needed to calculate the swap count correctly.

2) My formula #MinSwaps=N-C needs a proof... I didn't find it in the web.

Answer (score 0):

Well regardless of the input of the data, you should store it in 2D-array, type String. The empty spaces will be given a null value(similiar to StinePike;s model, imagine the null's in the space). After that it is quite simple to create the method transpose -- to loop in column-row order using the null value as a marker to jump to the next column.